# Using the stem form of a verb like the て form, as in 燃えゆく or 飲みほして

Tags: grammar, て-form, compounds, renyōkei

What is the significance of sometimes using the stem form of a verb like how the て form would be? For example:

> 燃えゆく (from HANABI)
>   飲みほして (from Ambiguous)

It's something I hear now and again, but never understood what its grammatical roots are.

Comment: Can you please give examples in the body of the question and not in the title? It will be easier to read. Also, maybe explain in more details.

Comment: What are "HANABI" and "Ambiguous"?  Are they even relevant to the question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[飲]{の}み[干]{ほ}す, [燃]{も}えゆく are compound verbs([複合動詞](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8B%95%E8%A9%9E#.E8.A4.87.E5.90.88.E5.8B.95.E8.A9.9E)): 飲む + 干す >> 飲み干す, 燃える + 行く >> 燃えゆく

> 例: 死にゆく、食べ続ける、話し終える、飛び立つ、言い出す... ← continuative form(連用形) verb + verb

---

Compare: 燃えてゆく(燃えていく) is made of the verb 燃える + the subsidiary verb([補助動詞](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%A3%9C%E5%8A%A9%E5%8B%95%E8%A9%9E)) ゆく/いく(行く).

> 例: 死んでいく、食べてもらう、話してくれる、飛んでくる、言ってしまう... ← te-form verb + subsidiary verb